# Envelope pattern in SoX (Sound eXchange) or ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, sox

I've been using SoX to generate white noise. I'm after a way of modulating the volume across the entire track in a way that will create a pattern similar to this:

[White noise envelope effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7Okl.png)

I've experimented with fade, but that fades in to 100% volume and fades out to 0% volume, which is just a pain in this instance.

The tremolo effect isn't quite what I'm after either, as the frequency of the pattern will be changing over time.

The only other alternative is to split the white noise file into separate files, apply fade and then apply trim to either end so it doesn't fade all the way, but this seems like a lot of unnecessary processing.

I've been checking out this example [Using SoX to change the volume level of a range of time in an audio file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127095/using-sox-to-change-the-volume-level-of-a-range-of-time-in-an-audio-file), but I don't think it's quite what I'm after.

I'm using the command-line in Ubuntu with SoX, but I'm open to suggestions with ffmpeg, or any other Linux based command-line solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ffmpeg, you could use the volume filter

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -af \
"volume='if(lt(mod(t\,5)/5\,0.5), 0.2+0.8*mod(2*t\,5)/5\, 1.0-0.8*mod(t-(5/2)\,5)/(5/2))':eval=frame" \
  output.wav
```

The expression in the filter above, increases the volume from 0.2 to 1.0 over t=0 to t=2.5 seconds, then gradually back down to 0.2 at t=5 seconds. The period of the envelope here is 5 seconds.

Comment: Simple and elegant answer. This worked perfectly. I'm wondering though, if I wanted to use a bunch of different length envelopes throughout the audio track, how would I go about doing this? Many thanks! :)

Comment: You would then daisychain multiple volume filters with each having an expression so their applications don't overlap i.e. if one filter creates the envelope between 30s and 50s,then no other filter alters the volume in that range (unless you want to). You daisychain like this: `-af "volume=..., volume=..., volume=..."`

Comment: Brilliant. This got me heading in the right direction, although I couldn't get the daisy-chaining working as you've suggested, but I managed to embed if-else statements within if-else statements i.e. `"volume='if (x, y, if (x, y, if(x, y, z) ) )`

Comment: What happened with the daisychaining?

Comment: In the first example using the daisychaining the output file is just silence  `ffmpeg -i input.wav -af "volume='if (between(t,  0,  5), (t/5)+ (0.2-((0.2/5)*t)))', volume='if (between(t,  5, 10), (1-(t-5)/5) + ((0.2 / (10-5)) * (t-5)))':eval=frame" output.wav`.  But in the second example, embedding the IF statements I get a smooth envelope: `ffmpeg -i input.wav -af "volume='if (between(t,  0,  5), (t/5)+ (0.2-((0.2/5)*t)), if (between(t,  5, 10), (1-(t-5)/5) + ((0.2 / (10-5)) * (t-5)) ) )':eval=frame" output.wav`

Comment: I was just adding it above, I pressed enter too soon! :)

Comment: In your 1st command, the first filter needs a `eval=frame`. Also, the first filter's expr can be simplified to `0.16t + 0.2`

Comment: And the 2nd filter to `1.5 - 0.1*t`

Comment: I tried the changes but a silent audio track is still returned. I temporarily changed the volume to 1 to help fault find.     `ffmpeg -i input.wav -af "volume='if (between(t,  0,  5), 1)':eval=frame, volume='if (between(t,  5, 10), 1)':eval=frame" output.wav`

Comment: Ok, the `if` is expecting three arguments, so the first one would be  `volume='if (between(t, 0, 5), 0.16t + 0.2 ,1)',` Just use `1` as the 3rd arg to leave volume unaltered if between returns false.

Comment: Genius!.. That worked perfectly. Thanks again for your time!!

Comment: As (t) travels through the audio track, working through my IF statements, does it adhere to some sort of frame rate? (As ffmpeg handles video too).    I ask because if I produce e.g 35 envelopes per second, some of them don't form properly at a sample rate of 44100. Zooming in on the waveform I see noticeable volume steps as apposed to a linear increase/reduction in volume. If my sample rate is 192000, this produces perfect envelopes, but I end up with very memory hungry audio files.  Is there a way to force ffmpeg to process the audio with more detail, without increasing the sample rate?

Comment: Filters only work on streams fed to it, so an audio filter working on a single audio stream is not concerned with any other video or audio stream in that file. Can you show the command you're currently using? One option is to sample to 192k, process, and then resample back to 44.1 kHz.